# How do I run an SSIS from stored proc using a SQL login without a job

Tags: ssis

How do I set up a SQL login to run a stored proc that executes an SSIS, without using a SQL job?

I have a working process (SQL Server 2016) where I build & run an SSIS execution directly from a stored procedure  (using a Windows service account). I am using the [catalog].[create_execution] method (so no SQL job).
Works great, dynamic parameters are set for the SSIS and it starts running while control returns to the service account.

Now we have a non-sysadmin user with a SQL login service account who wants to be able to call the same stored proc and run the SSIS.

- I know a SQL login cannot run IS Catalog stored procs, so it can't run the stored proc with the SSIS.
- The SQL login is used elsewhere so the user does not want to switch this connection to a Windows login, plus we want to keep this login with minimal permissions.
- The async nature of the SSIS call is exactly why I want this. The user only waits for the stored proc to kick off the SSIS and does not have to wait for the SSIS to complete before control is returned to the user.
- I do NOT want to use a SQL Agent job for the SSIS piece as I know I will sometimes call the stored proc/SSIS while the previous call is still running (runtime is <10 seconds). In this case I need them to run in parallel (the code has no issues running in parallel), and a SQL job can't start (fails) if the previous job is still executing.

I did create a Windows login specifically for this purpose. I thought I could have the SQL login "impersonate" the Windows login but ended up elevating both logins to sysadmin before it ran successfully. It works, but the elevated permissions will not be allowed in Production.

I've read more than a dozen similar questions that all say "create a job", but I don't want to (as described above) and there "should" be a way to do this without a job.... right? :)
Any suggestions/solutions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it always the same packages with consistent parameters that needs to be run by the sql user?

Comment: @billinkc - it is the same SSIS package with the same list of parameters, but the parameter values are different each time. ... Basically a SQL login randomly loads single rows to an interface table. The interface table i my source to load rows to a database. They want "near-immediate" transfer to the DB. I was trying to avoid a job that runs every 'n' seconds. So, thought is create a trigger on interface table to kick off an SSIS and return control to "user" while the SSIS runs in the background to load a row from interface table to DB.

Comment: Any appetite for Service Broker? Trigger shoves info onto a service broker queue. Your activation procedure executes as a service principal that has package running power. I've never tied SB with SSIS but I feel like it'd work

Comment: @billinkc - I'm not ruling anything out yet, but I have to admit I have not used it in the past.

Answer (score 1):

You have succinctly identified why assorted approaches won't work (+1). I'm still working through my tea so better (bad) ideas might come to me but what if you were able to have multiple jobs running concurrently? I think that'd solve your issue of allowing the SQL User able to run an SSIS package because you'd control "who" is presented to the SSISDB as the running user.

We can address the concurrent job execution by creating one-time, self-deleting jobs.

Allow the SQL user to execute the "JobMaker" procedure defined below.

### Job Maker

The first step the procedure does is generate the new job's name. In this case, it'll take the form of SubJob_2021-12-11_DEADBEEF-DEAD-BEEF-DEAD-BEEFDEADBEEF

Give it a good string to start the job name so things "sort nicely" in the gui. If you need to use this technique to run multiple packages, I'd embed the package name into the job name.

I add the date so if a job exists beyond today, that'd be my queue to see if it's still running or whether it errored out.

The GUID is a uniquely generated sequence so even if you and I both called the JobMaker proc at the exact same time, we'd still get a unique job created.

The rest of the procedure is me using the job creation wizard to run my SSIS package "Package.dtsx" in the project "JustWait" in the folder "So" and assigning values to the package parameters. I'd expect you'd do a similar thing  based on your specific requirements.

I specify `@delete_level = 1` which is delete the job on success so I don't clog my job list with one-time jobs.

The final step is to start the job with `sp_start_job`

```
USE msdb;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.JobMaker
AS
BEGIN
    -- "Magic" here - we build out a dynamic name for our job
    -- It takes the form of SubJob_ today's date as YYYY-MM-DD and then a unique guid 
    -- It creates the job and then as the last step runs the new job
    DECLARE @jobNameDynamic sysname = CONCAT(N'SubJob_', CONVERT(char(10), GETDATE(), 121), '_', NEWID());

    SELECT
        @jobNameDynamic;

    DECLARE @jobId binary(16);

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_job
        @job_name = @jobNameDynamic
    ,   @enabled = 1
    ,   @notify_level_eventlog = 0
    ,   @notify_level_email = 2
    ,   @notify_level_page = 2
    ,   @delete_level = 1
    ,   @category_name = N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
    ,   @owner_login_name = N'sa'
    ,   @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT;

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver
        @job_name = @jobNameDynamic
    ,   @server_name = N'ERECH\DEV2017';

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep
        @job_name = @jobNameDynamic
    ,   @step_name = N'JorbStep'
    ,   @step_id = 1
    ,   @cmdexec_success_code = 0
    ,   @on_success_action = 1
    ,   @on_fail_action = 2
    ,   @retry_attempts = 0
    ,   @retry_interval = 0
    ,   @os_run_priority = 0
    ,   @subsystem = N'SSIS'
    ,   @command = N'/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\So\JustWait\Package.dtsx\"" /SERVER "\"ERECH\dev2017\"" /Par "\"$Project::aDateTime(DateTime)\"";"\"1/1/2022 12:00:00 AM\"" /Par "\"$Project::aWideString\"";x /Par "\"$Project::anInt(Int32)\"";0 /Par "\"$ServerOption::LOGGING_LEVEL(Int16)\"";1 /Par "\"$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)\"";True /CALLERINFO SQLAGENT /REPORTING E'
    ,   @database_name = N'master'
    ,   @flags = 0;

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_job
        @job_name = @jobNameDynamic
    ,   @enabled = 1
    ,   @start_step_id = 1
    ,   @notify_level_eventlog = 0
    ,   @notify_level_email = 2
    ,   @notify_level_page = 2
    ,   @delete_level = 1
    ,   @description = N''
    ,   @category_name = N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
    ,   @owner_login_name = N'sa'
    ,   @notify_email_operator_name = N''
    ,   @notify_page_operator_name = N'';

    EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_start_job
        @job_name = @jobNameDynamic;
END;
```

You might additional requirements, like having a job run as a proxy user but this approach should address the big ticket items.

Otherwise, the impersonation that happens in the SSIDB for the package running conflicts with a sql defined user (until 2019?). The ways to start a package would be

- agent job
- SSISDB stored CLR procedures
- xp_cmdshell calls and even then, I think your dtutil calls will need to have a windows users to work - although you might be able to change your context but that's gonna be an even uglier hack.

Comment: Thanks billinkc, this is interesting and I really appreciate you taking the time. I may not use it for this solution, but I am definitely saving it for future use.